# Change color of node groups in a d3.js force node canvas layout

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js

I have a forced graph:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
        context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        width = canvas.width,
        height = canvas.height,
        min = 5;

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink()
                .id(function(d) { return d.id; })
                .iterations(2)
                .distance(function(d) {
                    return Math.sqrt((600 - d.value)) / 10;
                })
                .strength(8)
        )
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody()
                .strength(-300)
                .theta(0.9)
                .distanceMax(400)
        )
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2)
        )
        .force("collision", d3.forceCollide(1))
        ;


d3.json("/contigderivatives/data/", function(error, graph) {
    if (error) throw error;

    simulation
            .nodes(graph.nodes)
            .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation.force("link")
            .links(graph.links);

    d3.select(canvas)
            .call(d3.drag()
                    .container(canvas)
                    .subject(dragsubject)
                    .on("start", dragstarted)
                    .on("drag", dragged)
                    .on("end", dragended));

    function ticked() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

        context.beginPath();
        graph.links.forEach(drawLink);
        context.strokeStyle = "#aaa";
        context.stroke();

        context.beginPath();
        graph.nodes.forEach(drawNode);
        context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
        context.fillStyle = 'steelblue';
        context.stroke();
        context.fill();
    }
    function dragsubject() {
        return simulation.find(d3.event.x, d3.event.y);
    }
});

function dragstarted() {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.1).restart();
    d3.event.subject.fx = d3.event.subject.x;
    d3.event.subject.fy = d3.event.subject.y;
}

function dragged() {
    d3.event.subject.fx = d3.event.x;
    d3.event.subject.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended() {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d3.event.subject.fx = null;
    d3.event.subject.fy = null;
}

function drawLink(d) {
    context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
    context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
}

function drawNode(d){
    d.x = Math.max(min, Math.min(width - min, d.x));
    d.y = Math.max(min, Math.min(height - min, d.y));
    context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
    context.arc(d.x, d.y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
}
```

I'm trying to change the color of the nodes based on a grouping that is specified in the JSON that's an integer, where 0 = red, 1 = blue. There are plenty of examples of how to change the styles of a node when using SVGs, but there's not a lot when using a canvas. Changing the line `context.fillStyle = 'steelblue';` changes the fill color for all of the nodes.. How does one change the style and attributes of individual nodes when using a canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a color scale

```
 var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

Then on each node draw I color on the basis of node data properties:

```
  function drawNode(d) {
    context.beginPath();//for each node do begin path as context fill style and stroke are different.
    context.moveTo(d.x + 3, d.y);
    context.arc(d.x, d.y, 3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = color(d.group);//coloring on the basis of the group
    context.strokeStyle = color(d.group);
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
  }
```

Based on the bl.ock diagram you referred in the comment I have made a small working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oES8bgXJR1NO4tYtl99A?p=preview)

Hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: This results in every node being the same color. Part of the reason I didn't create a fiddle is that I can't seem to get a canvas example to work on it. https://jsfiddle.net/scvf47r0/   My force graph is exactly: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ad70335eeef6d167bc36fd3c04378048 with json exactly like: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/ad70335eeef6d167bc36fd3c04378048/miserables.json

Comment: please check my edited answer hope it fixes the problem. My feeling that all nodes are coming in the same color because you will need to do the begin path for each node.

Comment: Moving context.beginPath() into the drawNode function worked. Thanks!